# How long are the user sessions stored for in the Quick Start App before they have to re-auth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I could be wrong here but I think sometimes my glass app stops working and I have to go back to the application authentication in the browser.  Is this set to expire after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 4):

The access_token expires in about an hour, but most of the time when you get an access_token, you're also getting a refresh_token which allows the library to automatically get a new token for you. The refresh_token should remain valid until one of the following happens:

1. The user removed authorization for your Glassware. They can do this by turning off the Glassware in the console, or by using other OAuth2 deauth methods.
2. The user has requested "too many" refresh tokens, at which point older refresh tokens may get removed from the system.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout isn't explicitly mentioned in the docs, other than to say

> Access tokens have a limited lifetime

Source: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

My current starter project session has been active for over 24 hours.  So it is at least "days".

The token might become invalid and require refreshing if GAE is having authentication issues, which has been happening for Glass developers:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=99